# 'Subscript out of range' error when selecting a range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I'm getting a VBA error (`Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range`) when I am trying to select a workbook and then a cell within a sheet in that workbook.

`this_workbook` is correct, and copying and pasting the output into Windows `Run` results in the workbook opening. `data_worksheet` is also correct.

```
this_workbook = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

Debug.Print "Workbook name - " & this_workbook & vbCrLf
Workbooks(this_workbook).Sheets(data_worksheet).Range("A1").Select
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: If your question is specifically about code you have written, (like this one) you will get a broader audience willing and able to answer by asking on Stack Overflow instead of Super User.

Comment: @DanielCook - I have that dilemma every time I post about VBA. I've been told the exact oppisite in the past, and I have found that, as the majority of Office experts roam this forum, the answers may be fewer, but are often better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select a Range in a Worksheet that is not active.

Additionally, calling using `Workbook(this_workbook)` overly complicates your code.

Try replacing your code with this (Assumes data_worksheet represents a worksheet name or number):

```
With Thisworkbook.Sheets(data_worksheet).
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").select
End with
```

Now bear in mind that this code doesn't actually do anything other than select a cell in a particular sheet, so this macro isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Seeing that you activated the sheet within the workbook rather than just the workbook made it click, as I was on the wrong sheet! And FYI, the macro does do more than this, this is just the tidying up at the end of a function.

Comment: I was sure that you would eventually do something else. You just didn't share that part. I hope you get the rest working without problems.